# c# NLog how to get only one logfile with the longdate as filename

Tags: c#, nlog

Hello I am using for my console application NLog for logging.
With that being said I would like to log everything that happens in the console using NLog to set that up I am using the NLOG.config:

```
  <target name="FullCSVFile" xsi:type="File"  fileName="logs\internal_${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.log" keepFileOpen="true">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
    <column name="Console" layout="${message}" />
    <column name="Error" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
  </layout>
</target>

<logger minlevel="Debug" name="*" writeTo="FullCSVFile" />
```

But this way the tool makes a new file every second passed in the console, but I want to make one file when the tool starts with that timestamp and write everything in this one. How would I do that?

Comment: fileName = "logs\internal_${cached:cached=true:inner=${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.log}";

Comment: Have you read this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target ? If you are using time data in the file name you will get new log file for each time sequence. You better log into a constantly named file and add archiving. Is that unacceptable to you?

Comment: However, if you stick to this approach, you could try introducing a variable: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use the ambient property `cached=true` like this:

```
<target name="FullCSVFile" xsi:type="File"  fileName="logs\internal_${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}.log" keepFileOpen="true">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
    <column name="Console" layout="${message}" />
    <column name="Error" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
  </layout>
</target>
```

It will make layout render once, and then just return the same cached value.

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Cached-Layout-Renderer

To make it "perfect" then you could use `${processinfo:StartTime:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss:cached=true}` then the timestamp would be stable even after reloading NLog-config.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work, but I have not tested it:

```xml
  <variable name="started" value="${date:format=yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}"/>
  <target name="FullCSVFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs\internal_${started}.log" keepFileOpen="true">
    <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
      <column name="Console" layout="${message}" />
      <column name="Error" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
    </layout>
  </target>
```

The idea is similar to the example from the documentation: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables